# 401 unauthorized error consuming sharepoint webservice with soapui

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, soa, soapui

has any one tried accessing sharepoint webservices using soapui.
i am getting a 401 unauthorized error in response to my webservice request.

here is a response for reference :-

```
     HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthor      Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    SPRequestGuid: 8bf28e9c-d9b2-9011-4ed2-bb557583d071
    request-id: 8bf28e9c-d9b2-9011-4ed2-bb557583d071
    X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
    SPRequestDuration: 3
    SPIisLatency: 2
    WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
    Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 17:57:46 GMT
    Content-Length: 16

    401 UNAUTHORIZEDized
```

kindly advise.

the authentication methodology is claims based.

regards
Santosh

Comment: Where is your request? Where is authentication information?

Comment: tried that before posting this. NTLM support appears has a selectable option before performing a webservice request. the authentication mechanism defined is claims to access webservices, as advised by my service administrator.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI doesn't seem to work directly with NTLM authentication, but you can use a proxy such as Burp Suite to do the authentication for you.

This is explained here:

http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=17431

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this error by including Apache HTTPClientCommon API.